# alert statement is not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement, alert, modernizr

Here is my code:

```
alert("First");
if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.color) {
    alert("This form is optimized for a browser that supports html5. Using anything else may produce unexpected results. Use at your own risk.\n\nThis bowser doesn't appear to support html5.");
} else {
    alert("Second");
}
alert("Third");
```

This is run when the page is first loaded. The first alert statement works correctly. The second and third ones are not run at all. I've tried it in Chrome, Firefox, and Internet Explorer and I get the same result in all of them. Maybe Modernizr is messing something up? I don't know, I just copied and pasted the code. I've probably made a glaringly obvious mistake. (I've done it before) Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: `Modernizr` or `Modernizr.inputtypes` is probably undefined. What does the browser's error console show?

Comment: yes, Modernizr has an error, because third alert should works.

Comment: check your javascript console (shift-ctrl-j in FF/Chrome) and look for errors. Guess that `inputtypes` doesn't exist, or is capitalized wrong.

Comment: You should try "Modernizr.color" rather than "Modernizr.inputtypes.color".

Comment: Aha! I foolishly put this script before the one that included Modernizr. Thank you much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that `Modernizr` or `Modernizr.inputtypes` is `undefined` (probably because it wasn't loaded before this code), so `Modernizr.inputtypes.color` gives an error. Therefore, the following lines (which include the second and third `alert` statements) won't be executed.